# Combining Jenkins Pipeline and UrbanCode Deploy to achieve Continuously Delivery?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, urbancode

The best part of UrbanCode Deploy is it models a component based architecture application, and its deployment environment so well that everybody can understand in 10 minutes. Very initiative, flexible and powerful. Don't know if there is another tool does this well.

Jenkins Pipeline can orchestra the Continuously Delivery workflow at the higher level to include the build, test, etc.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1):

There's a new UCD plugin for Jenkins that adds nice integrations with the Jenkins 2.0 pipeline. I'm going to poke the developers since there doesn't seem to be a nice video showing it, but there is documentation (and a link to the plugin) out here:

https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/docs/jenkins-build-step-integration-with-ibm-urbancode-deploy/

I think the idea is that you can use Jenkins pipeline to govern the flow of a build through early test environments, while UCD owns the late test environments / production when the pipeline operates more at the snapshot level. Would love your feedback!

Comment: I always believe a tools is only good for its original purpose and that purpose only. Jenkins is just for build, I won't use it for deployment, it was not designed for that. UCD is much better for deployment. Using the same idea, I think we need a orchestration tool above all these build, test, deploy tools. It's time to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

Today, in my production environment, i use Jenkins to manage my build (like a "build pipeline" with some tests) and put all my build results into Urbancode Code station. Urbancode is doing all my deploy work perfectly, the integration with Jenkins is beautiful, easy and fast. I have read some articles about Jenkins delivery pipeline and do not recommend use it.

Check it out
https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/tools